# Clicking on active router-link

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

In my Vue 2 app, I have a menu bar whose menu items use router-link. One of these menu items is 'Customers', which takes the user to a customer editor. Now, if the user clicks on this same 'Customers' menu item while they're in the customer editor, nothing happens. I presume this is because of this behaviour mentioned in the docs: "In HTML5 history mode, router-link will intercept the click event so that the browser doesn't try to reload the page."

Now, that's perfectly understandable and for the majority of the time it would be the behaviour I want. But actually here I want the component to be reloaded, to go back to a clean slate. Or perhaps more accurately, for some event to occur which I can handle within the customer editor to set things how I want them to be. I assumed this would be the case, in fact, but when I set up a watch, thus

```
    watch: {
      '$route' (to, from) {
        console.log("Route changed");
      }
    },
```

I don't see anything logged to the console. It may be that some event is occurring which I'm not handling and that Vue is simply reusing the component. But how can I stop it from doing so?

Answer (score 6):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/1155), you can add a `@click.native` binding to the current `router-link` and reinitialize your component data in there.

But a quick and dirty solution would be to append a unique parameter to your route, like a date. Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/posva/2c2dfmqb/)

Comment: I may have to go down the rather unsatisfactory `@click.native` route. One major problem for me with that is that the function called cannot presumably be a method in the component. I'll take a further look at the fiddle to see if I can work around this.

Comment: What I've done for the moment is to use a global bus and in the @click.native function, emit a reset event with the name of the route. In the component I set up a listener for the reset event in mounted(), and then react accordingly. Works, and is reusable, but seems long-winded. Whatever I did I could not get the component to respond just to changes in route params.

Comment: Cool! I think an event/lifecycle hook that fires when a router-link is clicked, even if the route doesn't actually change, would be a great addition to vue-router

Answer (score 1):

The intended method of accomplishing this seems to be to implement a `beforeRouteUpdate` function to reset the properties of the route component.  See this issue on vue-router's GitHub: [Routing the same component, the component is not reload, but be reused? #1490](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/1490).

> This is expected behaviour, Vue re-uses components where possible.
>
> You can use the `beforeRouteUpdate` hook to react to a route switch that
>   uses the same component.

Comment: beforeRouteUpdate does not fire if the user simply clicks the menu item again. Presumably as there is no route change, and no parameter change, therefore there is no route update?

Comment: @JohnMoore You're right, take a look at [this issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/974).